# Widehat symbol at the same height of the text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, symbols, nomenclature

I use \widehat to indicate estimated values in a document. Then I need to prepare a table in which for instance I show in the superscript section of the table: * is a superscript for dimensionless quantities, widehat is used to indicate estimated quantities, etc. and I want the widehat symbol to stay right at the same height of the text in the adjacent column of the table in this case. How can I do?

Comment: Are you asking for a symbol that, like `\bigcup`. is vertically centered on the math axis?

Comment: Can you give an image of your desired output?

Comment: Maybe something like `\raisebox{-.5\height}{$\widehat{\quad}$}`, but it's difficult to understand what you are after.

Comment: The suggestion of @campa works quite well. I would like a widehat not positioned high as in `$\widehat{ }$` but at the same height as for example the plus symbol, +, in `$+$`. Thank you all.